# why my code is showing error undefined reference to `WinMain@16'?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, header-files

I wanted to use a function which I have defined on file h3.cpp in main.cpp for which I created a file h3.h and declared that particular function in the header file. but my file h3.cpp is not getting compiled and showing error--

> undefined reference to `WinMain@16'--

```
//main.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include"h3.h"

using namespace std;
int main(){
    intlog();
    log("hello");

    return 0;
}
```

```
//h3.cpp

#include<iostream>
#include"h3.h"
void log(const char* message){
    std::cout<<message<<std::endl;
}
void intlog(){
    log("world");
}
```

```
//h3.h(HEADER FILE)

#pragma once
#include<iostream>
void log(const char* message);
void intlog();
```

Comment: Are you building h3.cpp as well as main.cpp? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/4143855

Comment: If this is VisualStudio make sure you create your project as a console application rather than a windows application.  The latter has a different entry point (`WinMain`) than the standard `main` function.

Comment: @Tas i yes am building two files

Comment: @MilesBudnek i am using code blocks and i have created a console application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do changes in the project settings if you are using Visual Studio.

Go to the **Project** menu, your project properties, **Linker**, **System** and change the **SubSystem** option from **Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)** to **Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)** via the drop-down list.

Do changes in the project/target options if you're using Code::Blocks.

Goto **Build Targets**, the default setting for **Type**: **GUI application** - is incorrect for your project, change it to **Console application** via the drop-down list.

Comment: i am not getting such option in project setting. i am using code blocks. see this https://ibb.co/dKKD6cg

Comment: This menu structure is not from Code::Blocks.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah Read the answer carefully and completely.